# Scripting Address Coder actions in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, geocoding

I am currently using ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop that comes with the "Address Coder" tool. This tool has some features that I need as part of my geocoding requirements: in specific, the option to append FIPS codes to the output. However, I see that this option is not available if I use the geocoding feature directly from ArcMap or ArcPy (arcpy.GeocodeAddresses_geocoding function).

Is there a separate scripting API (through ArcPy) available for Address Coder so that I can use its additional capabilities?